# Flutter Firebase Remote Config. Help needed

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-remote-config

I have one String type variable API_URL in flutter and I want to get its value from Firebase Remote Config. I wrote following code to fetch it...

```
Future<String> get_api_url() async {
  final RemoteConfig remoteConfig = await RemoteConfig.instance;
  await remoteConfig.fetch(expiration: const Duration(hours: 0));
  await remoteConfig.activateFetched();
  return remoteConfig.getString('api_url');
}
```

It is returning value but I am not able to store it in variable named API_URL. May be I can use FutureBuilder but not sure what to do. So your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I want something like String API_URL = get_api_url();

Comment: If you have updates or additional information for your question, you can use the edit link at the bottom.  Don't use a comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: Have you tried String API_URL = await get_api_url();